# R-module whose endomorphism ring equals R

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

For a commutative ring $R$, there is a natural map $m:R\to\text{End}_R(M)$ of any $R$-module $M$.

Assume $M$ is finitely generated. If the map $m$ is an isomorphism, one speculates more or less that $M$ is a projective module of rank $1$. This is readily confirmed if $R$ is a PID or a Dedekind domain, since finitely generated $R$-modules are classified.

What assumptions one must impose on $M$ to make the speculation come true?

Comment: You should require $M$ to be finitely presented, as anyways f.g. projectives are finitely presented, and this allows $\operatorname{End}_R(M)$ to localize correctly. Now injectivity of $m$ is equivalent to $M$ being faithful, i.e. $\operatorname{ann}(M) = 0$. Thus by localizing at any prime of $R$, it suffices to show that $M$ is (locally) cyclic, i.e. can be generated by a single element, as being rank 1 free is equivalent to being faithful and cyclic

Comment: It's an interesting exercise to see for finitely presented modules $\operatorname{End}_R(M)$ localize correctly. I didn't know that. Thanks.